# Raw socket seems to get all packets in some cases, but not others

Tags: c#, sockets

I have a little program where I'm sniffing the raw packets coming in over my ethernet interface. My code looks like:

```
        Socket ReceiveSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Raw, ProtocolType.IP);
        EndPoint DefaultIPEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("10.0.2.0"), 0); // 10.0.2.0 is static ip on ethernet interface

        ReceiveSocket.ReceiveTimeout = 5000;
        ReceiveSocket.Bind(DefaultIPEndpoint);
        ReceiveSocket.IOControl(IOControlCode.ReceiveAll, new byte[4] { 1, 0, 0, 0 }, null);

        while (true)
        {
            byte[] ReceiveBuffer = new byte[512];
            int ByteCount = 0;

            ByteCount = ReceiveSocket.ReceiveFrom(ReceiveBuffer, ref DefaultIPEndpoint);
            // Handle Packets...
        }
```

What I'm finding is that this works only in certain implementations. By work, I mean that it actually receives all the packets on the interface. I can use wireshark to see whats coming, so I know about how much traffic I should receive, and when it "isnt working" it only receives a handful of packets, and they are only broadcasts (10.0.255.255) and what look like http notify's like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZs5p.png).

Now, it "works" when I build in debug, but not when I build in release. Additionally, I have this in its own standalone console app, and in another app where it works in a background thread. In the console app it works, but in the threaded app it does not work.

Any thoughts? Reasons why I might not be getting the rest of my packets?

EDIT: Looked at it again, and over wireshark, plus some breakpoints after receiving, and it looks like I can change my definition of "not working" to: I'm only getting the packets being sent. I'm not getting any of the packets received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going to answer my own question on this one. Turns out, it worked fine no matter the implementation once I tried it on a different computer with a different NIC. Leads me to believe that its a bug in my laptop's ethernet interface driver or something like that.